# Measure Javascript performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, profiling

I'm trying to do a full analysis of our front end and I'd like to know if there are any tools that can measure Javascript automatically.

Eg:

- Execution of functions (without the need for me to manually put date objects before/after to record this)
- What script on my page is the slowest and why
- Find out which functions I need to optimize
- Are there any jQuery improvements I could make (other than through John Resig's `jquery-profile.js`)

  - Better selectors I could use
  - Memoization on certain objects
  - Use of a better function (eg: use find because it's faster)

I'm pretty much looking for a profiler for my JS (and something that also profiles jQuery stuff), other than things like Firebug, the Chrome Dev Tools, Yslow/Page speed plugins etc. I'm looking for something better than JSlint or jsPerf.

I have New Relic running on my app, but it doesn't tell me where my scripts are lacking.

I was hoping there was an easier way to profile my JS than to do it manually. I need a drop in solution that does full analysis and gives me a report with metrics.

Comment: If you are using Chrome -> Right Click -> Inspect Element -> Network Tab and now again load page keeping network tab open ,it will give U report on when JS is loading and other things, Also I would strongly suggest look for "Page Speed" in google.

Comment: Page speed does not tell you anything about scripts performance. But other than that its a great tool for analyzing overall performance of page's assets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/

from doc intro to this:

> Using Speed Tracer you are able to get a better picture of where time
>   is being spent in your application. This includes problems caused by
>   JavaScript parsing and execution, layout, CSS style recalculation and
>   selector matching, DOM event handling, network resource loading, timer
>   fires, XMLHttpRequest callbacks, painting, and more.

Comment: it is add-ons? i can use this one for firefox also?

Comment: Sadly, Speed Tracer seems to have been abandoned. It is no longer in the Chrome store.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this recently, should help measure your javascript code performance - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/

Comment: Note that the User Timing API is presently supported by Chrome and IE but not Firefox or Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-timing

Answer (score 1):

You can also check a javascript library by Yahoo [Boomrang](https://github.com/yahoo/boomerang).It is an amazing tool to capture the user experience on a beacon server and triage/analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool I created : http://yellowlab.tools

It loads a page with PhantomJS and analyzes many things while the page is loading. Launch a test, then click on the "JS Timeline" tab. You will find a log of every JS function that interacts with the DOM, including jQuery functions.

I use it to audit JS code for my customers and it's the best existing tool when you need to untangle some spaghetti code, or understand some minified third party widgets!

Answer (score -1):

I really doubt that you can do that automatically else it would not make sense to hire senior devs to identify such problems :) What you could do is use Chrome dev tools and manually check your pages with CPU profiler and Timeline tools just to see what's running slow or what's creating memory leaks.

Good luck